# how does parsnip know how to match `fit` arguments to function arguments for a model?

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-parsnip

I am trying to create a new model for the `parsnip` package from an existing modeling function `foo`.

I have followed the [tutorial](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/develop/models/) in building new models in parsnip and followed the [README on Github](https://github.com/tidymodels/parsnip/blob/228a6dc6975fc91562b63d191e43d2164cc78e3d/R/README.md), but I still cannot figure out some things.

How does the `fit` function in `parsnip` know how to assign its input data (e.g. a matrix) to my idiosyncratic function call?

Imagine if there was an idiosyncratic model function `foo` where the conventional roles of `x` and `y` arguments were reversed: i.e. `foo(x,y)` where `x` should be an *outcome* vector and `y` should be a *predictor matrix*, bizarrely.

For example: suppose `a` is a matrix of predictors and `b` is a vector of outcomes. Then I call `fit_xy(object=my_model, x=a, y=b)`.  Internally, how does `fit_xy()` know to call `foo(x=y,y=x)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way we do this is through the `set_fit()` function. Most models are pretty sensible and we can use default mappings (for example, from `data` argument to `data` argument or `x` to `x`) but you are right that some models use different norms. An example of this are the Spark models that use `x` to mean what we might normally call `data` with a `formula` method.

The random forest `set_fit()` function for Spark looks like this:

```r
set_fit(
  model = "rand_forest",
  eng = "spark",
  mode = "classification",
  value = list(
    interface = "formula",
    data = c(formula = "formula", data = "x"),
    protect = c("x", "formula", "type"),
    func = c(pkg = "sparklyr", fun = "ml_random_forest"),
    defaults = list(seed = expr(sample.int(10 ^ 5, 1)))
  )
)
```

Notice especially the `data` element of the `value` argument. You can [read a bit more here](https://parsnip.tidymodels.org/reference/set_new_model.html).

Comment: thank you @JuliaSilge, that `data` field is what i was looking for. However, the `data` field of `value` is not documented in the linked page, nor on the vignette for building a parsnip model from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

The function to validate the input is `check_final_param`, which require that each argument e.g. have to be named. That is why order is not important.
https://github.com/tidymodels/parsnip/blob/f7ba069671684f61af0ca1eadb1927fedec8a9c6/R/misc.R#L235

The README file linked by you pointing out:
"To create the model fit call, the protect arguments are populated with the appropriate objects (usually from the data set), and **rlang::call2** is used to create a call that can be executed. "

Example of randomForest which using `ntree` instead of default trees argument.
They created a translation calls which will be used during evaluation.
https://github.com/tidymodels/parsnip/blob/228a6dc6975fc91562b63d191e43d2164cc78e3d/R/rand_forest_data.R#L339

If we use `call2` and unpack the named args the order does not matter. And as we know that args will be properly named because of additional translation step.

```r
args <- list(na.rm = TRUE, trim = 0)

rlang::call2("mean", 1:10, !!!args)
```

Comment: But this does not explain how the *main* arguments are matched.  "To create the model fit call, the protect arguments are populated with the appropriate objects (usually from the data set)", but nowhere is it specified how to match arguments `x` and `y` in `fit_xy()` to some idiosyncratic function `foo2(p,q)`. How does it know to assign `x` to `p` and `y` to `q` instead of the other way around? I tell it how to assign *auxiliary* arguments to `foo2` via `set_args`, but `set_args` does not cover the "main" arguments (predictor matrix and outcome vector).